# WPF deployed to Store missing some functionalities

Tags: wpf, uwp-xaml, windows-store, msix

I've published a WPF app to the Microsoft Store. While it generally runs find I do find that some functionalities are missing. For example - I'm using TaskbarItemInfo to indicate stats on the Taskbar icon but it doesn't seem to make any effect.
(sample)

```
            Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
            {
                TaskbarItemInfo.ProgressValue = value;
                TaskbarItemInfo.ProgressState = pstate;
            }));
```

I did find out that when I go to the path installed by the store (C:\Program Files\WindowsApps...) and **copy the content to another folder on my hard drive, everything works fine**.
This leads me to believe the problem is around a more restricted permissions for the store folder, but it's only an assumption at this point.

My questions are:

- Is there any knowledge or docs around restrictions for store apps?
- Is there a way to simulate the store environment without publishing? Feels like trial & error is not very effective

Link to the app (just for reference): [link](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9NHW8HQ6KVQ4)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any knowledge or docs around restrictions for store apps?

Yes, there is a document that lists the things you need to know before you package your desktop application. Here is it: [Prepare to package a desktop application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-prepare).

> Is there a way to simulate the store environment without publishing? Feels like trial & error is not very effective

Generally, I'd suggest you create a sideload desktop-bridge package, then deploy and test it in your device first. This should be easier to find out issues than directly upload it to the store.